# MVVM для начинающих

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь вникнуть в суть MVVM, рассматривая простейшие примеры и мне непонятны некоторые вещи,такие как:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
```

Также непонятно как работает интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`
Может ли кто-нибудь все это объяснить?
P.S. на MSDN и других сайтах был и читал,но понятнее не стало

Comment: А что вам непонятно в приведенном примере?

Comment: @Vlad интерфейсы,классы, методы

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробую объяснить.

Между `View`(графический интерфейс программы (кнопки, текстовые поля, и проч.)) с помощью так называемого байдинга (кто-то называет биндинг, хотя это неправильное произношение) устанавливается связь со свойствами во ViewModel. Например с текстовым полем ввода мы связываем свойство `(ViewModel)` - `public string Name { get; set; }` с помощью записи в `XAML` `(View)` `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"`. Для того, чтобы можно было оповестить текстбокс о том, что данные в свойстве `Name` изменились (допустим в ходе каких-либо вычислений) и текстбокс "перечитал" данные из `Name` в блоке `set;` этой переменной необходимо вызвать событие `PropertyChanged`.

Для этого во `ViewModel` реализуют (наследуют) от стандартного интерфайса `INotifyPropertyChanged`. В вашем примере используется один из вариантов такой реализации:

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` - собственно само объявление нужного события.

`public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")` - вспомогательный метод для вызова этого события из блока `set;`.

`[CallerMemberName]` - атрибут у параметра, который позволяет не указывать название свойства программисту, компилятор сам подставит имя свойства, которое вызывает метод `OnPropertyChanged`, т.е. вы можете вызвать как `OnPropertyChanged("Name")` или же так `OnPropertyChanged()` и тогда `("Name")` вместо вас подставит компилятор.

Далее в самом методе происходит проверка; а если ли у этого события подписчики? И в случае наличия таковых (у нас это  `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"`) происходит вызов события с передачей в качестве аргументов: класса вызывающего это событие и имя свойства, которое изменилось.

Такой вариант вызова события не единственный, в интернетах и в книгах можно найти еще пару-тройку вариантов. Все это дело вкусовщины. Лично я люблю прямой вызов события, что называется "в лоб", покажу на примере, может вам станет все еще яснее.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged //не забываем о наследовании
```

Присваиваем в объявлении события пустой делегат, чтобы потом не заниматься проверкой, а если ли подписанты на событие? Они теперь всегда есть, по крайней мере один пустой подписант.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

А вот пример свойства с вызовом этого события (использую новую конструкцию `nameof()`, чтобы передать название свойства)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Имя скачиваемого видео файла
    /// </summary>
    private string _NameFileVideo;
    public string NameFileVideo
    {
        get { return _NameFileVideo; }
        set
        {
            if (_NameFileVideo == value) return;
            _NameFileVideo = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NameFileVideo)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что основное, что вас пугает в этом коде - события.

Не уверен, что получится понятно объяснить, но попробую провести аналогию.

Каждый день в мире происходит множество событий, как глобальных так и локальных. Но о большинстве из них вы никогда не узнаете по той простой причине, что они вам не интересны. Вы хотите узнавать лишь те новости, которые важны для вас и ваших близких. Таким образом ставя "фильтр" вы **подписываетесь** только на интересующие вас события - например, на новости космонавтики. Тоже самое делает элемент управления вашего приложения через интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. 
Другими словами для элемента управления это и есть фильтр на тематику новостей от объекта. Если объект не реализовал интерфейс - значит он ему не интересен.

Что касается привязки данных (`Binding`)...если проводить аналогию дальше, то это уже будет более конкретный фильтр (например, вас интересуют только новости с Марса). Так и элемент управления интересуется актуальными данными только от тех свойств объекта с которыми он непосредственно работает и он ничего не знает и не хочет знать обо все остальном что происходит в вашем классе.

Когда вы изменяете значение свойства в коде - это уже событие. Но ни элемент управления, ни кто-либо другой об этом ничего не знает. Именно поэтому когда вы хотите "опубликовать" новость вы пишите:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Название свойства")
```

и тот элемент управления, который подписался на получение новостей об этом свойстве отреагирует должным образом.

---

Атрибут `CallerMemberName` просто позволяет получить имя метода или свойства объекта, который вызывает метод. В данном случае используется, чтобы избежать возможных ошибок связанных с неправильным названием свойства для обновления.